# how do i remove a woo-commerce widget?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets

[image]

How do I remove that widget that is to the left of the screen, I want the product page to take the full width of the browser window and for the life of me cannot find out how to remove it.

It says the following

> This is a WooCommerce Widget Area. You may add widget here from
>   Customizer or Appearance -> Widgets. Or to hide this you may select
>   full width layout for shop in customier.

I'm using the new store theme.

Answer (score 1):

The message is suggesting you can hide this area by going into the admin backend customizer.

You can find these setting in the customizer by going to Admin > Appearance > Customize.

[image]

Once you have the customizer open the exact setting will depend on your theme.  It may be nested under the WooCommerce tab or another tab created by your theme.  Just poke around and look for a way to change the "Store Page" layout to "Full Width".

[image]